# Why ping/latency lower in-game than command prompt?

Tags: networking, ping, gaming, udp, icmp

Is it weird that when i tested my ping to a specific gaming server on cmd, and it showed a constant and stable 42 ms (never below that), and When i played on that server in the game, it showed my ping was around 35 ms - 43 ms? (39 ms avg.) So which one is more accurate, reliable and more real-time for my test? Could it be that the ICMP protocol is a little bit slower than UDP protocol? Or is it only a matter of different ports and configurations?

Comment: http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1695075

Comment: When firewalls are configured, ICMP is typically given the lowest priority.  So because of this ICMP could be "slower" than UDP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most games are fairly inaccurate at determining ping from in-game. Many games don't measure ping at all, but rather game traffic latency, i.e. time taken for an actual game action to complete.

OS native ping is almost always more accurate.

There are exceptions, but since you didn't say what game you were talking about, I can only answer generically.